# Ending a program with ctrl+Z

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassAverage
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String names[] = new String[50];
        int scores[] = new int[50];
        int entries = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter number of entries");
        //int entry = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the names followed by scores of students: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            names[i] = in.next();
            scores[i] = in.nextInt();
            entries++;
        }
        Average avg = new Average();
        double average = avg.CalcAvg(scores,entries);

        System.out.println("The class average is: " + average);
        avg.belowAvg(scores,average,names,entries);
        avg.highestScore(scores,names, entries);
    }
}
class Average
{
    Average()
    {
        System.out.println("The averages: ");
    }
    double CalcAvg(int scores[], int entries)
    {
        double avg;
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        {
           total += scores[i];
        }
           avg = total/entries;
        return avg;
    }

    void belowAvg(int scores[],double average,String names[], int entries)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        {
            if(scores[i] < average)

                System.out.println(names[i] + "You're below class average");

        }
    }

    void highestScore(int scores[],String names[], int entries)
    {
        int max = scores[1];

        for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        {
            if(scores[i]>=max)
                max=scores[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum score is: " + max);
        System.out.println("The highest score acheivers list: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        {
            if(scores[i] == max)
                System.out.println(names[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

im suppose to hold the ctrlkey press z and then press the enter key to end the program but how do i do that?

if you are wondering the program is to write a program that lets the user input student names followed by their test scores and outputs the class average, names of students below the average, and the highest test score with the name of student

Comment: why should you want to ctr+z then enter to exit the program?

Comment: teacher wants it that way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl-Z is the DOS command code for end of input (the UNIX equivalent is Ctrl-D). All command line programs should support this because it allows you to pipe output from one as input to the other. Kudos to your teacher!

When this key combo is pressed, `Scanner.hasNextLine()` will return false. Here's an example of a loop that reads line until you hit Ctrl-Z on Windows (or Ctrl-D on Linux/Unix):

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("You wrote " + in.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: So, basically it means that a read() will return -1 under Windows? Interesting to know

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for the control-z character in your scanner:

```
String nextLine = in.nextLine();
if(nextLine.length == 1 && nextLine.charAt(0) == KeyEvent.VK_Z)
  // end program
```

Comment: What if caps-lock is on? what if using foreighn keyboard? Why not use `VK_Z`?

Comment: It is NOT SURE AT ALL that a control character gets transmitted as is to a program. For instance, C-c on a Unix shell will send a SIGTERM to the process, it will not send the control character at all (and C-z will send SIGTSTP)

Comment: @fge That's fine, he wants to stop the program anyway so if the program gets stopped by this if statement or by SIGSTP it doesn't matter based on the problem description, because he didn't say he has to do any cleanup.

Comment: @aguibert even then, I highly doubt that C-z even under Windows sends the character as is

Comment: It should be `KeyEvent.VK_C`.

Comment: VK_C is actually the char 'C'.  We should be using KeyEvent.LAST_LINE_END which is ^z.

Comment: Not sure if `LAST_LINE_END` even exists, what should it represent?